# find -newerct filter on cp-copied files has different result compared to original files

Tags: find, cp, timestamps

I've migrated some 73k files from `source/` to `dest/` with `cp -pR`. Before I did that I checked with `find source/ -type f -newerct $(date -d @1623247288 +"%Y-%m-%d")` that I can grab new files. I could – [thanks, SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964747/recursively-find-all-files-newer-than-a-given-time).

But when I try that same filter on the `dest/` files the filter doesn't work anymore. Can anyone please tell me if they know what could have went wrong here? [Allegedly](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040904/846446), copy's preserve flag carries over the timestamps.

When checking a random file for its time that shows up although it shouldn't, it shows a time that isn't newer than 1623247288 // Mi 9. Jun 16:01:28 CEST 2021:

```
$ date -ur dest/random-file.jpg
Mo 26. Jun 08:23:19 UTC 2017
```

Comment: `ctime`, the change-status time cannot be set arbitrarily, it's only set to the current time any time any change is done to data or metadata (other than atime) of the file, `cp`  or anything else cannot preserve it after copy. `date -r` reports the mtime (after symlink resolution), not ctime

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. That was definitely something I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to achieve this with `-newerct`, but as a workaround, I am getting better results for my needs with `-newermt`. Might be a matter of defining what "preserving timestamps" means.

Copy timestamps after the fact, if necessary:

```
$ touch -r <original_file> <new_file>
```

Q: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040886/846446